# 2 lines in a listView item

Tags: android

I would like to have two lines in every list view item. This is my code but, it's not working.

```
public class nea extends ListActivity{
    private List<Message> messages; 

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) { 
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
        loadFeed(ParserType.DOM);
    }


    private void loadFeed(ParserType type){
        try{
            Log.i("News", "ParserType="+type.name());
            FeedParser parser = FeedParserFactory.getParser(type);
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            messages = parser.parse();
            long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            Log.i("News", "Parser duration=" + duration);
            String xml = writeXml();
            Log.i("News", xml);
            List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>(messages.size());
            for (Message msg : messages){

                String o = titles.get(messages.size());
                if (o != null) {
                    TextView tt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                    TextView bt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
                    if (tt != null) {
                         titles.add(""+msg.getDate());                            }
                    if(bt != null){
                        titles.add("date: "+ msg.getTitle());
                    }return;
            //titles.add(msg.getDate()+"\n"+msg.getTitle());
                }
            //  titles.add(msg.getTitle()+"  "+msg.getDate());

            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row,titles);
            this.setListAdapter(adapter);
        //  textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(titles.get(position)));

        } catch (Throwable t){
            Log.e("News",t.getMessage(),t);
        }
    }
```

SECOND WAY--not working too

```
    List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>(messages.size());
                for (Message msg : messages){       

                        String o = titles.get(messages.size());
                    if (o != null) {
                        TextView tt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                        TextView bt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
                        if (tt != null) {
                             titles.add(""+msg.getDate());                            }
                        if(bt != null){
                            titles.add("date: "+ msg.getTitle());
                        }return;
                //titles.add(msg.getDate()+"\n"+msg.getTitle());
                    }
                //  titles.add(msg.getTitle()+"  "+msg.getDate());

                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
                    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row,titles);
                this.setListAdapter(adapter);
            //  textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(titles.get(position)));

            } catch (Throwable t){


Log.e("News",t.getMessage(),t);
        }
```

Comment: You'll need to post all the code for this, its not clear what you are doing there. What is messages? How are you setting up your data source, adapter and list view?

Answer (score 21):

In order to create a `ListView` with two lines of text on each item, I use a `SimpleAdapter` in the following way:

Create a `List` that will hold your data. Each Map entry will have a Key (First line) and a Value (Second line) of each one of the `ListView` Items.

```
List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
```

For each pair we want to put in the `ListView`, create a `HashMap` and add it into the List declared before.

```
Map<String, String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
                datum.put("First Line", "First line of text");
                datum.put("Second Line","Second line of text");
                data.add(datum);
```

Note: if you want to add more than one row, then you need to create another object similar to `datum` above.

Then declare a `SimpleAdapter`. Note there the use of "First Line" and "Second Line" strings inside the constructor. This will tell the adapter how to use the strings of the `Map` declared before. Note too the use of the layout `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` and the text id `android.R.id.text1` and `android.R.id.text2`.

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, 
                    new String[] {"First Line", "Second Line" }, 
                    new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 });
```

You then need to set `adapter` as the adapter of your `ListView`

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.theIdOfYourListView);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Should we create simple_list_item_2.xml or its already defined? If we should can you share the code ? I found some xml layout but theyre not working...

Comment: @albatross if you want to modify and use simple_list_item_2.xml file then go to this link...
[link](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res/layout)

Comment: This is such a simple solution that works immediately!

Answer (score 2):

I am just using inflating Twoline listitem xml layout.In the following example text1 is Header and text2 is subtitle.

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private String[] stringArray;
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater inflator;
    int checkbox;
    /**
     * 
     * @param context
     * @param stringArray
     */
    public CustomListAdapter(Context  context, String[] stringArray) 
    {
        this.mContext=context;
        this.stringArray=stringArray;
        this.inflator= (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return stringArray.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        final MainListHolder mHolder;
        View v = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            mHolder = new MainListHolder();
            v = inflator.inflate(android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, null);
            mHolder.txt1= (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            mHolder.txt2= (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
            v.setTag(mHolder);
        } 
        else
        {
            mHolder = (MainListHolder) v.getTag();
        }
        mHolder.txt1.setText(stringArray[position]);
        mHolder.txt2.setText(stringArray[position]);

        /*mHolder.txt.setTextSize(12);
        mHolder.txt.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
        mHolder.txt.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);*/
        //mHolder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);


        return v;
    }
    class MainListHolder 
    {
        private TextView txt1;
        private TextView txt2;

    }



}
```

And also there is a [Example](http://www.codercorp.com/blog/android/android-two-line-listview-with-custom-data.html) on Twoline listitem

Answer (score 1):

If you can take all titles or line 1 in one array and all details or line 2 in another array, You can do like this is in simple way using SimpleAdapter

```
String[] titleArray = {"title 1", "title 2", "title 3", "title 4"};
String[] detailArray = {"detail 1", "detail 2", "detail 3", "detail 4"};

List<Map<String, String>> listArray = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=0; i< titleArray.length; i++)
{
    Map<String, String> listItem = new HashMap<>();
    listItem.put("titleKey", titleArray[i]);
    listItem.put("detailKey", detailArray[i]);
    listArray.add(listItem);
}

SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listArray,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
        new String[] {"titleKey", "detailKey" },
        new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 });

ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listId);
listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

The lines:

```
TextView tt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
TextView bt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
```

are meaningless because there isn't a list item view for `msg` at that point, and you are not finding the text views by ID within a list item view, but rather the main view.

When your app first starts, you have an empty `ListView`. You then parse messages as part of `onCreate` (which is not a good idea, by the way, because time-consuming processes should not be performed in the UI thread) and then proceed to attempt to find non-existent text views by the IDs `R.id.TextView01` and `R.id.TextView02` in the main view.

Keep in mind that you will need two layout XML files: one for the layout of the list activity and another for the layout of each list item. Also keep in mind that `findViewById` queries for a view *within* another view. In this case, it's trying to query the main view, but that does not have the text views `TextView01` and `TextView02`; text views `TextView01` and `TextView02` are elements of the list item views that are obtained by inflating the list item layout.

I highly suggest that you start with one the API demos first, so that you can see a complete, working example of something similar to what you are trying to accomplish. For example, http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html

Comment: @kostas: I think that you should read some tutorials on `ListView`. I found one that looks really good: [http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-example/](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-example/). Try reading through that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care too much about layout and stuff and just want multiple lines on a listview. The easiest way to do that is like this with the carriage return '\n'

```
xList = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.xlist);
mItems = new List<string>();
ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, mItems);

xList.Adapter = adapter;
adapter.Add("FirstLine\nSecondLine\nThirdLine\nEtc");
```