# How to add simple product query in android App

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android. I have some Products like a0, a1, a2. I want to add their definitions in the second line as x0, x1, x2.

Here is my main code:

```
private ListView lv;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_eagle);

 String products[] = {"a0", "a1","a2", };
 String definitions[] = {"x0", "x1","x2",};

lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    // Adding items to listview
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

### What I find:

a0

---

a1

---

a2

---

**How can I find them in this way:**

---

a0

x0

---

a1

x1

---

a2

x2

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837834/2-lines-in-a-listview-item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your adapter to something like this:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, products){
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null)
             convertView = View.inflate(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, null);

        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(products[position]);
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(definitions[position]);

        return convertView;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Waqas. Could you please help me one more... [Download This](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15065300/To-Use-Custom-Font.zip)

Answer (score 0):

**-** The **default** `ArrayAdapter` can handle **only one** `TextView`.

**-** So if you want to do something like displaying 2 `TextView`, then its better to go with `Custom ArrayAdapter`.

**See this link for Custom ArrayAdapter example:**

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429